# How can i pass my url parameters as variables in a RESTful API using Python

Tags: python, json, rest, web, server

I have written the back-end code to retrieve information from an existing API that passes in three inputs (attribute1, attribute2, and API_key) to return a JSON document.

Now, I am trying to use the web.py module to connect to a server on port 8080 using Python. I am designing a RESTful API and I want to take in the parameters that a user types into the URL, and pass those as arguments into the above function to return the JSON document.

This is my simple web server code.

```
import web
import existing_api

attribute1 = ' '
attribute2 = ' '
api_key = ' '
url = ('/existingapi/'+attribute1+'/'+attribute2+'/'+api_key, 'index')
#print url
class index:
    def GET(self):
        return existing_api.retrieveInfo(attribute1, attribute2, api_key)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = web.application(url, globals())
    app.run()
```

I have written my back-end code in existing_api.py and I would like for a user to be able to enter "localhost:8080/:attribute1/:attribute2/:api_key" 
into the browser and return existing_api.retrieveInfo(attribute1, attribute2, api_key). What is the best approach to do this?

Also, when I try to hardcode the attributes and api_key, the URL returns a "not found" message. However, if I change the code for the url:

```
url = ('/existingapi/'+attribute1+'/'+attribute2+'/'+api_key, 'index')
```

to read

```
url = ('/', 'index')
```

without the attributes and type in localhost:8080, I receive the information I am looking for from the hardcoded attributes. Can anyone explain why this is the case? Thanks.

Comment: Are you tied to web.py? If not, you may want to take a look at [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Seconded. This is what Flask does really well (and django although that is a much bigger framework for something so simple). Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't need to,  (perhaps you need to tho?)